Radioshack LEDs triggered by computer HDD light: how do I trigger these multi colored LEDs to change color. Grounding 3rd lead triggers them
I have purchased Radioshack LEDs, catalog 276-0016. These are a 3-lead LED package with GND, VDD and a MODE pin. Each grounding the MODE pin changes the color or operation mode of the LED. I want to use this to replace a single-colour LED on my computer's hard drive activity LED.
When I ground the MODE lead, the LEDs change color but the problem is the HDD light has one 5 V wire and the mother board grounds the other LED pin but not low enough to trigger the Radioshack LED's MODE pin.
I'm trying 2N3904 transistors but still not good and also thought about a 741 op amp but 5 volts isn't enough of a supply voltage.  It also depends on how hard the mother board is accessing the HDD light.  An HDD speed test gets me 1 volt at negative HDD LED which still doesn't trigger the add-on Radioshack LEDs.
Here is where I got some of the info, but I cannot seem to find an actual datasheet on it.   https://forum.arduino.cc/t/the-radio-shack-7-color-led-and-you/76419.
[Edit by @Transistor] That article references this MSGBB557TA datasheet.


Welcome to EE.SE. Please [edit] to add a datasheet link for the parts so we know what you're asking about. (Don't add it in the comments where it won't be visible and may be deleted.)

I've cleaned up your question, supplied some missing information and added the datasheet link. Please review and see if it is correct. (You can compare the before and after by clicking the "edited ..." link below your post.)

If the MSGBB557TA datasheet link I edited into your question is the correct one then you are exceeding it's maximum operating voltage.

Figure 1. These specifications seem to match those on the Radioshack package in your question.
If you exceed the maximum ratings you cannot expect the device to operate normally - or at all - ever again!
It looks like a 3.3 V regulator might do the job but then you also need to prevent the MODE pin being taken to 5 V.
